# Java Netbeans static compiling

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm writting a Java library wich requires Gson to work, the problem is that if I want to distribute it I need the user to download Gson and add it to his project to be able to run my library, is there some way to include automatically Gson in my library and distribute it all together? I'm using the Netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [maven dependency mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Comment: And have a look at the appassembler plugin. http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/